# Coding an Hausdorff second-countable space into $[\omega_1]^{<\omega}$

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, set-theory, examples-counterexamples

Assume $\mathtt{CH}$ and take an Hausdorff second-countable space $X$ of the size of the continuum (i.e. $\omega_1$ since we are assuming $\mathtt{CH}$). Consider a map $\varphi: X\cup \mathcal{O}(X) \rightarrow [\omega_1]^{<\omega}$, where the latter is the set of all finite subsets of $\omega_1$, with the following property:

> For all $x\in X$ for all $U\subseteq X$ open subset, if $x \in U$ then $\varphi(x)\cap\varphi(U) \neq \emptyset$ otherwise $\varphi(x)\cap\varphi(U) = \emptyset$

Does such a map exists? Why (not)?
Ideas? Suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no: such a map does not exists.
Suppose that such a map exists and fix one, fix also $\mathcal{B}$ a countable base for $X$, then  $D = \bigcup_{B \in \mathcal{B}}\varphi(B)\subset \omega_1$ is countable.
If we define $\varphi': X\rightarrow [D]^{<\omega}$ as $\varphi'(x) = \varphi(x) \cap D$ then $\varphi'$ needs to be injective, but its range is countable, contradiction.